# Returning angular promise in angular service module

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js, promise

So basically I am using angular to gain access to a json file, where I am searching for a user  with a corresponding email. Then I need to find this user and return it from the service module. I then need the returned result to be a promise. Here is what I have so far...no progress the last couple of hours

```
getUser: function(authenticationName) {

            if(!(_.str.contains(authenticationName, "@"))) {

                return resource.get({userName: authenticationName}).$promise;
            }
                else if(_.str.contains(authenticationName, "@")) {

                    resource.query().$promise.then(function(data) {

                        var emailsArray = [],
                            userNamesArray = [];

                        _.map(data, function(user){ emailsArray.push(user.email); });
                        _.map(data, function(user){ userNamesArray.push(user.userName); });

                        if(_.indexOf(emailsArray, authenticationName) !== -1) {

                            var indexOfUser = _.indexOf(emailsArray, authenticationName),
                                user = userNamesArray[indexOfUser];

                            return resource.get({userName: user});

                        }

                    });



                }
        },
```

and the angular controller, where I get"cannot call method then of undefined":

```
userData.getUser(user.authenticationName)
                    .then(function(data) {
```

Until this moment everything is fine, if I can return the user from here and then call the resource.get() method it'll be all fine

```
return resource.get({userName: user});
```

Comment: You forgot return before the resource.query(..).$promise.then ? (And a throw after the if that returns in the then)

Comment: Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/5q9nQ/1/) what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but you should also do something meaningful if you don't enter the `if`, for example - throwing an error to indicate an application problem.

Comment: OK, but in the .then function in the other module the result is undefined, so the whole thing returns undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: console.log("Passed"); does not log from here on, if that will help
    resource.query().$promise.then(function(data) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a new promise, because of the elaboration in the `else` statement.

You can use angular's $q, or ES6's Promise to accomplish your goal.

**getUser:**

```
function(authenticationName) {

  var deferred = $q.defer(),
      ret;

  if(!(_.str.contains(authenticationName, "@"))) {

    ret = resource.get({userName: authenticationName});
    deferred.resolve(ret);
  }
  else {

    resource.query().$promise.then(function(data) {

      var emailsArray = [],userNamesArray = [];

      _.map(data, function(user){ emailsArray.push(user.email); });
      _.map(data, function(user){ userNamesArray.push(user.userName); });
      if(_.indexOf(emailsArray, authenticationName) !== -1) {

        var indexOfUser = _.indexOf(emailsArray, authenticationName),
                                user = userNamesArray[indexOfUser];

        ret = resource.get({userName: user});
        deferred.resolve(ret);

      }

    });
  }
}
```